# React Native: Difference in image display Android vs iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to show remote images that scale with flexbox surrounded by a white border and Android and iOS both don't handle my solution the way I would like them to.
iOS only shows the white border while Android only shows the image.

[image: Different Image display for iOS and Android]

This is the corresponding code. Any pointers where the problems originate from?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import Header from './../Header';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';


export default class DailyArticlesScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.displayName = 'DailyArticlesScreen';
}

render() {

    return (

        <View style={this.props.style}>
            <Header text='Heute'/>
            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
                    dummyData.articles.map(item => {
                        return (
                                <View style={styles.contentItem} key={item}>
                                    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                                        <Image 
                                            source={{uri: 'http://placekitten.com/100/100'}}
                                            style={styles.image}
                                            resizeMode="contain"
                                        />
                                    </View>

                                    <View style={styles.teaserTextContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.teaserTitle}> Title </Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.teaserText}> Lorem ipsum </Text>
                                    </View>

                                    <View style={styles.arrow}>
                                        <Icon name='chevron-right' size={30} color="#5d686d" />
                                    </View>

                                </View>

                            )
                    })

                }


            </View>
        </View>

        );
}
};

const styles={
container: {
    flex: 9,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
},
contentItem: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#929292'

},
imageContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    padding: 20
},
image: {
    flex: 1, 
    borderWidth: 5, 
    borderColor: '#fff'
},
teaserTextContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    paddingTop:20
},
teaserTitle: {
    fontWeight: '700',
},
arrow: {
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}


};

const dummyData = {
    articles: [1,2,3]
};
```

Comment: if you add a borderRadius to the image do you see the effect on iOS?

Comment: I do, even the Anroid picture gets a border radios. Still no white border on Android

Comment: Ok, this is a guess but try removing resizeMode='contain' and set a fixed height and width to your images just to see if they'll render on android.Tell me if they do

Comment: Will try, but remember; the problem is no border on android, no render on ios

Comment: Even with fixed width, no image on iOS

Comment: So the example from the webpage is still working with iOS. Might be rooted in the fact that there is no proper '.jpg' ending in the url...

Comment: So,  placekitten doesn"t seem to be bale to convice react-native that it delivers images. Borders around Images don't seem to be working on Android in general (much like around Text). I changed the URI, adjusted the view around the image and now it works. Will answer this question when SO allows me to